# How to pivot a column's values, making new, enumerated columns with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have a dataframe like:

```py
    id diag  a_date
0    1   d1      55
1    1   d2      88
2    2   d5      22
3    2   d3      44
4    2   d4      88
5    2   d4      89
6    3   d1      11
7    3   d1      13
8    3   d1      15
9    3   d5      27
10   3   d5      28
11   3   d5      29
```

`df = pd.read_clipboard() # copy the above text and run this to set df`

And I want to reshape it so that the `diag` values become enumerated columns with `a_date` values like:

```py
  id d1_1 d1_2 d1_3 d2_1 d3_1 d4_1 d4_2 d5_1 d5_2 d5_3
0  1   55             88                              
1  2                       44   88   89   22          
2  3   11   13   15                       27   28   29
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a posible solution.

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=["id", "diag", "a_date"])
df["enumerate"] = df.groupby(["id", "diag"]).cumcount() + 1
df = df.pivot_table(index="id", columns=["diag", "enumerate"], values="a_date").reset_index()

df.columns = [f"{col[0]}_{col[1]}" for col in df.columns]
df = df.drop(columns=["id_"]).fillna("")
print(df)
```

---

```
  d1_1 d1_2 d1_3 d2_1 d3_1 d4_1 d4_2 d5_1 d5_2 d5_3
0   55             88                              
1                       44   88   89   22          
2   11   13   15                       27   28   29
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
delimiter = '|'
_df = df.pivot_table(index=['id'], columns='diag', values=['a_date'], aggfunc=(lambda x: delimiter.join(str(v) for v in x)))
_df = _df.droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
_df.columns.name = None
_df = _df.reset_index()
#    id        d1   d2   d3     d4        d5
# 0   1        55   88  NaN    NaN       NaN
# 1   2       NaN  NaN   44  88|89        22
# 2   3  11|13|15  NaN  NaN    NaN  27|28|29

cols = df.diag.unique().tolist()
dfs = [_df.id]
for col in cols:
    _dfX = _df[col].str.split(delimiter, expand=True, regex=False) # regex kwarg pandas>=1.4.0
    _dfX.columns = [f'{col}_{c+1}' for c in _dfX.columns]
    dfs.append(_dfX)
df_f = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).fillna('')
#    id d1_1 d1_2 d1_3 d2_1 d5_1 d5_2 d5_3 d3_1 d4_1 d4_2
# 0   1   55             88                              
# 1   2                       22             44   88   89
# 2   3   11   13   15        27   28   29
```